# Made for three only

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The answer to this puzzle is a two word phrase (13 letters in total) where the first word starts with W. Good Luck! ;)

---

[image]

Hint 1

> [image]

Hint 2 (more decisive)

> Apply "hint 1" on all three grids. The small squares shows you how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So this is a bit of a long shot, but is the answer

> **Winners Podium?**

> As Mattia guessed in his answer, you can get the chemical symbols Ag, Au, Cu, and Sn by swapping the letters in the three grids using the pattern at the top of the image and then tracing the path shown at the bottom of the image. These symbols correspond to silver, gold, copper and tin. Gold, silver and bronze (an alloy of copper and tin) are typically used in competitions as the winning prizes for first, second, and third place, respectively.

> When the competitors are awarded their prizes, they are often standing on a platform or *podium*, with gold standing on the tallest platform, and silver and bronze standing on slightly shorter platforms to either side. The three grids are meant to visually resemble this "**Winners Podium**": Silver is found on the left (Ag), gold on the top (Au), and bronze on the right (Cu and Sn).

Comment: Well done - note that rot13(oebamr vf bsgra pbccre cyhf gva!)

Comment: Oh, right! rot13(v tbg zl zrgnyf zvkrq hc unun. v'yy rqvg zl nafjre gb vapyhqr gung, gunax lbh!)

Comment: Good job! All three grids are correctly interpreted, however rot13(zl vagragvba jnf gung gur vagraqrq nafjre fubhyq qrfpevor gur vzntr. V npghnyyl ernyvmrq vg vfa'g abeznyyl(V guvax) pnyyrq jung V vagraqrq ohg qrpvqrq gb yrnir vg yvxr gung. Jung qbrf gur vzntr ybbx yvxr? Jvgu tbyq ba gbc naq fvyire gb gur evtug bs gur tbyq jvaare naq oebamr gb gur yrsg bs gur tbyq jvaare. J------ C-----.)

Comment: Ah, I think I know what you're looking for in that case. I'll modify my answer a little bit.

Comment: Everything looks good now, well done :)

Answer (score 2):

> After having swapped all the letters in the three grids, we can overlap the path and the grids reading the string "agaucusn".
>  We can also write it as AgAuCuSn, i.e. Ag (Silver), Au (Gold), Cu (copper), Sn (tin). 
>  Among these four elements, gold has a lower melting point, so I guess that **WELDING SOLDER** is *Made for three only!*

Comment: Nice! Welcome to the site :-)

Comment: Nice job, but not the intended answer. You're correct regarding rot13(fvyire naq tbyq. Gel znxr frafr bs gur ynfg tevq. Jung pbhyq vg cbffvoyl zrna?)

Comment: I should add, rot13(gurl ner vaqrrq pbccre naq gva)

Comment: I guess I am too late :) timezone and crazy start of the work week did not help...Nice puzzle, I had fun!